# Is it possible to order a list based upon a custom set of values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <ul id="theIndexContainer">
        <li id="listItem" popVal="2"></li>

        <li id="listItem" popVal="0"></li>

        <li id="listItem" popVal="1"></li>

        <li id="listItem" popVal="4"></li>

        <li id="listItem" popVal="3"></li>
    </ul>
```

E.g. Changing the order of this list on a website in the order of popVal?? If so then how is this done?

Comment: Many things are possible in programming. The first step is often to try to write some code. Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Here.

```js
const sortLI = (a, b) => a.dataset.popval-b.dataset.popval;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let sorted = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#theIndexContainer li')).sort(sortLI);
  let ulList = document.querySelector('#theIndexContainer');
  ulList.innerHTML = '';
  
  sorted.forEach(i => {
    console.log(i);
    ulList.appendChild(i);
  });  
  
  
});
```

```html
    <ul id="theIndexContainer">
        <li id="listItem" data-popval="2">2</li>

        <li id="listItem" data-popval="0">0</li>

        <li id="listItem" data-popval="1">1</li>

        <li id="listItem" data-popval="4">4</li>

        <li id="listItem" data-popval="3">3</li>
    </ul>
```